# Sync failed when adding new benchmark module

Tags: android, benchmarking, androidx, android-jetpack

I was trying to create new benchmark module as describe [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/benchmark#create-module), but my project sync failed with following error

```
Detected usage of the testInstrumentationRunner,
                            androidx.benchmark.AndroidBenchmarkRunner, in project benchmark,
                            which is no longer valid as it has been moved to
                            androidx.benchmark.junit4.AndroidBenchmarkRunner.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing

```
testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.benchmark.AndroidBenchmarkRunner'
```

to

```
testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.benchmark.junit4.AndroidBenchmarkRunner'
```

in benchmark module's gradle file fixed the issue.